# C++ Problems only on macOS for "while(cin>>str)"

Tags: c++, macos

Here's the code that is causing issues:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main(){
    using namespace std;
    vector<string> v;
    string s;
    while(cin >> s)
        v.push_back(s);
    cin.clear();
    cout << endl;
    for(auto &i : v)
        cout << i << "\n";
    cin >> v.at(0);
    for(auto &i : v)
        cout << i << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code on Windows, I can use CTRL+Z to stop the while-loop in order to execute the next few lines, including the line `cin >> v.at(0)"`.

But when I run it on my Mac, even if I use Xcode, VSCode, CLion or any other IDE, the whole program terminates when I try to use Control+D (I know ctrl+z does not work on macOS or Linux) to stop the loop. This means the `cin >> v.at(0)` line is never executed.

What is causing this?

Comment: Very often, the IDE:s are the problem. What if you run your program directly from the command line?

Comment: You probably need a call to `ignore` after `clear` to actually purge the input buffer

Comment: I've seen Control-Z work just fine on a Mac terminal. Are you using "Control" or "Command"?

Comment: Even i add the ```ignore``` after ```clear``` and run it from the command line, it also doesn't work. When i enter ```111\n222^Z```, it directly quits as the output result is ```zsh: suspended  ./main```.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://superuser.com/q/805727/29943

Answer (score -1):

> the output result is `zsh: suspended  ./main`

You're encountering terminal processing.  The Control+Z combination has been recognized and converted to a `SIGTSTP` by the terminal (and the shell likely handles this by sending your program a `SIGSTOP`)

If you want to actually deliver a control character to your process standard input stream, it's not sufficient to press Control+Z in the terminal window.  You'll have to escape it.  The specific key sequence to escape depends on your terminal program.

Comment: But we are talking about Ctrl + D, not Z? I never encountered a terminal program that failed to process Ctrl + D properly.

Comment: @ChristianHalaszovich: Check the comments under the question, he was told to use `cin.ignore()` and said that when he tried that together with Ctrl+Z, he got the specified output from `zsh`.  So OP is indeed talking about Ctrl+Z as well as Ctrl+D.  Furthermore, the ASCII code for "end-of-file" is 26 (Z)